# jQuery fullcalendar view modification and popup event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Has anyone worked with jQuery Full Calendar ? Here is little bit of modification i am looking for

Below is the code which fetches a calendar :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        events : http://someurl,

        eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window
            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
            return false;
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            }else{
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }

    });
```

I am looking to have it in three different view Day,Week,Month as in below code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                url: 'http://google.com/'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

But

1. I am not sure how to integrate my first code with second one?
2. `onclick` event show popup alert

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay
                },
                true // make the event "stick"
            );
        }
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
            end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            start: new Date(y, m, 28),
            end: new Date(y, m, 29),
            url: 'http://google.com/'
        }
    ],

     eventClick: function(event) {
        // opens events in a popup window
        window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
        return false;
    },

    loading: function(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            $('#loading').show();
        }else{
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    }

     });

 });
```